# Can I setup SignalR for Azure API Apps?

Tags: signalr, azure-api-apps

I am using Azure Api App and having a need of push notifications back to client devices. Does Azure Api App support this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can host your SignalR hub in an Azure App Service API app.  That said, an App Service Web app works fine as well.  In fact, that is my recommendation unless you need the incremental features provided by API Apps for other scenarios.  In particular, you avoid the need for the gateway that is part of API Apps.

Comment: Could you give me an example for that? Thanks.

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc.

Comment: Thanks. But I need an example working with Azure Api App, not this one.

Comment: MSFT has published a guide here: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites Don't forget to turn on the Websockets setting!